# Batch file explore directory for PostgreSQL connection

Tags: postgresql, batch-file

Once again, I am asking for your help to manage a small batch script.
As announced, in a previous post, I'm used to work on linux and automation tasks are more obvious to me but I have to work today under Microsoft environment.
Writting a Batch file is definitly not an easy things.
I am able with this script to be connected to a PostgreSQL database and load data via ogr2ogr. Until then, no problem.
Currently, the path of the folder is hard written in my code, but I would like to have the possibility of choosing the working directory through windows explorer.
Also, concerning this directory, I would like to have the possibility to process the subfolders at the same time.

Here, below the piece of my *.bat code:

```
TITLE Upload Shapefile Files to PostgreSQL
@echo off
cls
color 9
echo ******************************************************************************
echo *                   Upload Shapefile Files to PostgreSQL                     *
echo ******************************************************************************
set /P Host=Please enter your Server Host (default:localhost):
set /P Port=Please enter your PGSQL port (default:5432):
set /p Database=Please enter your PGSQL Database Name (default:postgres):
set /P Schema=Please enter your Edigeo Schema (default:public):
set /P User=Please enter your PGSQL username (default:postgres):
set /P Password=Please enter your PGSQL password (default:postgres):
For /F %%H In ("C:\Users\stephj\Desktop\SHP\*.shp") do ogr2ogr -overwrite -t_srs EPSG:2154 -s_srs EPSG:2154 -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=%Host% port=%Port% user=%User% password=%Password% dbname=%Database%" -lco schema=%Schema%
pause
```

Thanks in advance for your time and your help.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I would like to have a popup windows to browse and select the folder.

Comment: You can't do that with a batch file. You will need to look into other scripting languages PowerShell, AutoIt or something similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is a way. This will just demonstrate by echoing the files, you need to amend it to follow your command structure:

**Note!!** This is a batch/PowerShell hybrid script. It needs to be saved with a batch file extension, preferably `.cmd`:

```
@echo off
set "pshell="(new-object -COM 'Shell.Application').BrowseForFolder(0,'Select Folder',0,0).self.path""

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell %pshell%') do set "workdir=%%a"
for /r "%workdir%" %%i in (*.shp) do echo "%%~i"
```

Comment: Ok, I have adapted what you gave me with things that should suits me as below.
`set "pshell="(new-object -COM 'Shell.Application').BrowseForFolder(0,'Select Folder',0,0).self.path""
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell %pshell%') do set "workdir=%%a"
for /r "%workdir%" %%i in (*.shp) do echo C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4\bin\ogr2ogr.exe -append -t_srs EPSG:2154 -s_srs EPSG:2154 -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=%Host% port=%Port% user=%User% password=%Password% dbname=%Database%" "%%~i" -lco schema=%Schema%
pause`
I receive back the answers but they are not executed.

Comment: you need to remove echo in the for loop :) also please double quote your path in that line. So from `do`, it should be `do "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4\bin\ogr2ogr.exe" -append -t_srs EPSG:2154 -s_srs EPSG:2154 -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=%Host% port=%Port% user=%User% password=%Password% dbname=%Database%" "%%~i" -lco schema=%Schema% `

Comment: Like a charm ! Thanks @Gerhard Barnard